# 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my SQL

```
INSERT INTO `products` (
                product_code,
                displayname,
                type,
                retail,
                wholesale,
                available
            )
            VALUES (
                "carrot",
                "Carrot & Fennel"
                "loaf",
                9.50,
                7.50,
                1
            )
```

My Table Columns are:

- product_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
- product_code VARCHAR NOT NULL
- displayname VARCHAR NOT NULL
- type VARCHAR NOT NULL
- retail FLOAT NOT NULL
- wholesale FLOAT NOT NULL
- available INT NOT NULL

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a comma after `"Carrot & Fennel"`

```
INSERT INTO `products` (
                product_code,
                displayname,
                `type`,
                retail,
                wholesale,
                available
            )
            VALUES (
                "carrot",
                "Carrot & Fennel",
                "loaf",
                9.50,
                7.50,
                1
            )
```

**Result**

```
1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings

Query: INSERT INTO `products` ( product_code, displayname, `type`, retail, wholesale, available ) VALUES ( "carrot", "Carrot & Fennel",...

1 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.078 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.078 sec
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe it was so simple.

Comment: @Vromoth NP. Kindly mark answer as accepted if this solves your question, thank you.